# Output MP4 file to Servlet from URL Source

Tags: java, servlets, video, mp4

For a project I am working on I have a few MP4 video files sitting on a Server. 
A Java based web app I am writing needs to play these files in the browser. Due to a security restriction, only the server hosting the web app has access to this server, the browsers using the web app do not have access, making it impossible to use HTML 5 for play back.

The solution I am working on, is having a servlet (sitting on the web app server), access the video file. Write the video as it's output, and have the servlet be the source for the HTML player.

However I seem to be unable to successfully output the video file as servlet output in a streaming fashion.

I've done a large amount of research. The closest thing I came to a solution is this:

```
private static final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024 * 16;
private static final long EXPIRE_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
private static final Pattern RANGE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("bytes=(?<start>\\d*)-(?<end>\\d*)");

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    URL video = new URL("http://localhost/App/Videos/FileSD.mp4");
    URLConnection yc = video.openConnection();
    yc.setDoOutput(true);

    int length = yc.getContentLength();
    int start = 0;
    int end = length - 1;

    int contentLength = end - start + 1;

    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(BUFFER_LENGTH);
    response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", yc.getLastModified());
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis()
           + EXPIRE_TIME);
    response.setContentType(yc.getContentType());
    response.setHeader("Content-Range",
            String.format("bytes %s-%s/%s", start, end, length));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.format("%s", contentLength));
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);

    ReadableByteChannel input = Channels.newChannel(yc.getInputStream());

    int bytesRead;
    int bytesLeft = contentLength;
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_LENGTH);

    try (OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream()) {

        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1 && bytesLeft > 0) {
            buffer.clear();
            output.write(buffer.array(), 0,
                    bytesLeft < bytesRead ? bytesLeft : bytesRead);
            bytesLeft -= bytesRead;
            output.flush();
        }
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

For the most part, this code works fine, it takes a URL as input, and streams it as Output. The problem is, it only works for HD video files. SD video files simply don't play. Was hoping anyone has any idea why that is, and how it can be fixed.